# could not find mail-service.xml in jboss 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

I am using JBOSS 6 in domain mode to configure the mailing service. I know from Jboss 7 the mail service configuration is moved to standalone-*.xml or domain.xml. Could you please let me know whether I can still use the mail-service.xml in jboss 6 domain or it is moved to a domain configuration ? Kindly let me know how we can configure mail configuration in jboss 6 onwards, will dropping the mail-service.xml to deploy folder work?

Answer (score 0):

From JBoss 6, you can configure mail via the `mail subsystem`.
I would advise you to read the following chapter for more details:
[MAIL SUBSYSTEM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap-mail_subsystem)